# Objective C - UICollectionView - Double tap zoom on full

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, zooming

I need some help on zooming whole collectionView with double tap. I have searched a lot on internet but most of answers are relating with UIScrollView and Pinch gesture. I am adding already a pinch gesture which is invaliding layout collectionView and returning scale. I need some solution like that into double tap zoom which give me scale so i can calculate item sizes on run time.

Any suggestion?

## edit

```
- (void)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
  
   static CGFloat scaleStart;
   static CGPoint p;
   
   if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
   {
   scaleStart = self.scale;
   p = self.collectionView.contentOffset;
   }
   else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
   {
   CGFloat tempScale = scaleStart * gesture.scale;
   if (tempScale < MINIMUM_SCALE)
   {
   self.scale = MINIMUM_SCALE;
   }
   else if (tempScale > MAXIMUM_SCALE)
   {
   self.scale = MAXIMUM_SCALE;
   }
   else
   {
   self.scale = tempScale ;
   }
   
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   
   [self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
   
   //self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, p.y * gesture.scale);
   });
   }


-(CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat collectionCellWidth =  ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
    
    return CGSizeMake(collectionCellWidth * self.scale, collectionView.frame.size.height * self.scale );
}
```

Comment: Does your pinch gesture work? Show us the code.   If that works, you can hook up a tapgesture to do something similar

Comment: @LouFranco Please see my edited question. I have added code there.

Comment: Does that pinch code work? If so, you could create a tap gesture that sets self.scale and invalidates -- have you tried it -- if so, show code and tell us what part you are having trouble with